# Mail Merge vs Document Generation?

Tags: templates, pdf-generation, document, auto-generate, mailmerge

I'm looking for a Node or Python Package/Module, that helps me work with document templating, and whenever I lookup this subjects, I get many out of date packages or redirect to HTML template engines...

My problem is, that I have many MS Word Templates and PDF, and I want to be able to query the fields on each template, so I can be passed them in properly, and occasionally generate a series of documents from one record of data.

Any help on how should I look up this? because I can't find it, but I think is that I don't know the Term, Document {Auto}Generation, Mail Merge, Document Templates {Node,Python}, Word Templates {Node,Python}... and I can't get anything useful.

Comment: How do your MS Word Templates files relate to the PDF files that you have? It is unclear what have, and what you want. Screenshots would help a lot.

Comment: I want to do the same as word with the letter and mailing feature, but as a web services, so I can send a json and it serves me the document(s)

Comment: Docmosis can do this but it is not free.  The examples here https://www.docmosis.com/resources/cloud/cloud-code-samples.html show Node Python examples of calling the API.  Please note I work for Docmosis.